# Como fica a view.blade.php que carrega os dados para um bootstrap carousel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Estou tentando carregar os dados dinamicamente a partir de um banco mySql, para um bootstrap carousel, com laravel 5.3. Está acontecendo o seguinte: Os dados são carregados, mas o carousel não funciona, isto é, fica estático, com uma imagem por cima da outra. Acredito ser um problema na view, que a seguir vai o código para melhor percepção. Desde já, agradeço antecipadamente.

**View home.blade.php**

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-home" data-ride="carousel">


         <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        @foreach($noticia as $notic)
            {{--<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{$i}}"></li>--}}
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ $loop->index }}" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"></li>
        @endforeach
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        @foreach($noticia as $item)
            <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <img src="{{$item->imagem}}" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="background-color: rgba(4,162,183,0.9)">
                    <p><h3>{{$item->titulo}}</h3></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endforeach

    </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução!!!
O problema estava nesta linha:

```html
<div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

**O correcto é:**

```html
<div class="item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

removendo **carousel-**